# Obtain Euribor Rates with ECB SDMX Rest API

Tags: ecb, sdmx

I need to obtain the euribor rate for 3 months with the ECB SDMX REST API (https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/help/) in node. Which URL should I use?

I tried to use this one:

https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/M.EURIBOR.R3.N?startPeriod=2022-02-01&endPeriod=2022-02-28&detail=dataonly

but I get the following error:

```
Validation error: Mismatch between the number of dimensions used in the series keys (M.EURIBOR.R3.N) and the number of dimensions defined in the data structure definition (5).
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For Euribor 3M you can use this endpoint (ECB SDMX Rest API):

https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/FM/M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA?lastNObservations=24&detail=dataonly&format=jsondata

They migrated the API from https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu to https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu

## How to build the url?

(Source https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/api/data)

1. we need to create this kind of url

   protocol://wsEntryPoint/resource/flowRef/key?parameters
2. protocol is **https** since 2021
3. wsEntryPoint and it is **data-api.ecb.europa.eu**
4. resource is **data**
5. flowRef is the dataflow and you can choose it from https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets and it's the value of the column "Identifier". Euribor belongs to Financial market data (Other data) that is **FM**. (Here what I really did to know that Euribor belongs to FM is that I searched for "euribor" in the ECB website, opened the correct chart (this one https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets/FM/FM.M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA) and whatched its category).
6. key you should defining the dimension values. I was ok with the Euribor 3M chart dimension values (the chart is here: https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets/FM/FM.M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA) so I used **M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA**
7. parameters you can add this optionals parameters startPeriod=value&endPeriod=value&updatedAfter=value& firstNObservations=value&lastNObservations=value&detail=value&includeHistory=value . I just used **lastNObservations=24&detail=dataonly&format=jsondata** . You can find more info about parameters and values here https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/api/data

Joining those 7 components you will get

https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/FM/M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA?lastNObservations=24&detail=dataonly&format=jsondata